# Solidity: Restrict access to functions

Tags: solidity, function

Today I found a contract on etherscan providing a restriction on one of the two existing "withdraw" methods and I asked myself: If you would call this function withdraw() as not the owner, will the restriction apply anyways, cause it is calling a restricted function?

```
  function withdraw() public {
    // delegate to `withdrawTo`
    withdrawTo(msg.sender);
  }

  function withdrawTo(address _to) public onlyOwner {
    require(_to != address(0), "address not set");
    uint256 value = address(this).balance;
    require(value > 0, "zero balance");
    uint256 developerFee = value / 33;
    value -= developerFee;
    payable(_to).transfer(value);
    payable(developerAddress).transfer(developerFee);
    emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, _to, address(this).balance);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the modifiers will work even if the function is called inside another function.

I have tested it in Remix and the function seems to work as intended, and only the owner can use it.